# кастомизация стиля контрола

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть некий контрол, а именно `TextBox`

И следующий прописанный мною стиль  :

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="SearchBox">

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                BorderThickness="1"
                                BorderBrush="Gray"
                                Name="Border">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="24"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <TextBox Style="{x:Null}"
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"
                                    Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                    FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                                    FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                    FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}"
                                     BorderThickness="0"/>


                            <Image Source="../UIResources/search.png"
                                   Width="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                                   Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                                   Focusable="False"
                                   Grid.Column="1"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

    </Style>
```

Проблема в том что когда TextBox не в фокусе, на нем нету курсора мышки и он не зафокушен клавиатурой, но внутри него стоит каретка, он не меняет цвет `Border`

Comment: скриншот будет?
А в чём вопрос заключается?

Comment: @codename0082016 как можно задать стиль на текстбокс, когда в нем производится ввод, без хардкода с эвентами.

Answer (score 1):

Решилось следующим способом :

```
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
```